# How to emulate clicking with help of JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to emulate clicking on a button on a page in mobile Chrome with help of JavaScript? Is there any way to do this?  It would be great if you could point me to an example. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this ain't the right way to ask questions. Please take a look at the help section first: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: `element.click()`

Comment: You really don't need to write code to emulate a `click`, just call the same code that you would have called if the button had actually been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Please be more detailed in your post, include some code so we know what you are actually doing, try reading the guidelines for a post before asking a question.

Now depending on what you are trying to do there is other ways to accomplish certain key presses, but we do not know or have any clue currently what your code looks like.

**So here is an example:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the checkbox to simulate a mouse-click.</p>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()" onclick="alert('click invocation occurred')">
</form>
```

Comment: @Jack Bashford, thanks I will remember to do that next time.

Comment: `click()` is not an event - it's a method invocation. `click` is an event.

Comment: Well, it's still not right. `click()` is not part of JavaScript. `click` is a method of a DOM object which is implemented by the browser. JavaScript is a language you can use to interact with the DOM.